# Unexplained PUT requests to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Every 2 - 6 seconds,a file is put to my S3 bucket in AWS. I have not been able to determine where these are coming from. I turned on CloudTrail for the bucket and the cloud trail logs do not show where the messages are coming from. At first I thought it was due to the bucket being configured for static web hosting, so I disabled that, but the messages keep coming.  I tried to delete the bucket, but it needs to be empty to delete and I can never empty it quickly enough to make eligible for deletion.

The bucket is not public, and I set up the Access Analyzer to confirm this.

Asking the question on this forum because forums.aws.amazon.com is not letting me in and I'm too cheap to pay for a support option at AWS.

By the way, all the messages look like the below

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ***bucketname***[05/Mar/2021:01:33:40 +0000] - svc:s3.amazonaws.com XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX REST.PUT.OBJECT 2021-03-05-01-33-40-1C3D198B880E8F3A "PUT /***bucketname***/2021-03-05-01-33-40-XXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 447 80 56 "-" "-" - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2

I do not have any processes running every 2 seconds.  Turned off the Cloudwatch alarms in case these were part of some health check but they didn't stop.  Has anyone ever encountered this?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be posting your S3 signatures in a public forum (at least _I think_ that log file excerpt shows your S3 signatures)

Comment: If you just want to delete the bucket, you can add a bucket policy to deny all the PutObject actions.

Comment: Why not configure the bucket as read-only, then delete everything inside of it, then delete the bucket? **Why are you allowing arbitrary `PUT` requests in the first place**? That's how you end-up with  warez in your bucket - or worse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,all, for the **quick** replies. I couldn't find a quick way to make the bucket read-only, so I took the path of setting the bucket policy. When I took a look at the policy that was already there for the bucket, I noticed this element in the policy

```
    {
        "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "billingreports.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxx/*"
    }
```

I removed it, then the PUT requests stopped. I may've added that policy a year ago when I was doing the AWS Mythical Misfits tutorial.

Bucket deleted.  Thanks again. all!

Comment: Or you could disable [Cost and Usage Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/cur-create.html) that you previously enabled, that's causing these objects to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that these files are pushed to S3 bucket when "server access logging" is enabled (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-server-access-logging.html) - this would result in small files being written to a bucket every second or so.

If this is the case, this can be disabled by removing write privileges from `S3 log delivery group` in the bucket's ACL.